# .Net Core 1.0.1 installation failing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone help me here, I tried installing VS2017 and it keeps failing. As per the logs, its was unable to install .Net core.

Now I am unable to figure out how to resolve this.Below are the logs

> Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{adfa1ec9-2075-4eec-9bb5-3f647f8e8e48}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
>    Acquiring package: VC_redist.x64.exe, payload: VC_redist.x64.exe, copy from: C:\Users\snowstorm\Downloads\VC_redist.x64.exe
>    Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\Users\snowstorm\Downloads\'
>
> Error 0x80070490: Failed to find expected public key in certificate chain.
>    Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify expected payload against actual certificate chain.
>    Error 0x80070490: Failed to verify signature of payload: VC_redist.x64.exe
>    Failed to verify payload: VC_redist.x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\VC_redist.x64.exe, error: 0x80070490. Deleting file.
>    Error 0x80070490: Failed to cache payload: VC_redist.x64.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to not having VC_redist.x64.exe installed in your machine

Install this from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615460

And then try reinstall .NET Core.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. Maybe I have downloaded different version of redistribute package.

Basically, I had issues installing VS2017 which it wasn't able to install completely and .net core failed.

Now I will try to install vs2017, If you have any tips please share.

Thank you so much